# Is there some literal dictionary or array syntax in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, llvm, clang, objective-c-literals

It's always been possible to create NSArrays (and NSDictionaries/NSNumber) with vararg method calls, like:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

Can these be created with in-line literals in a new improvement to LLVM and Clang?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

With [this change](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/?view=log&pathrev=152137) to the LLVM codebase, Apple has added a new syntax for literals in upcoming versions of the Clang compiler.

Before, arrays were created using a C-based array and were converted on the fly into Objective-C objects, such as:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
```

Note that since this is a varargs element, you had to supply an ending 'nil' at the end of the list. However, now there's an easier way:

```
NSArray* array = @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ];
```

Note that the leading @ before the [] is required, to distinguish between it and an and ordinary C array (or a message send). Note also that the trailing 'nil' is no longer required.

A similar change has been made for in-line dictionary literals, similar to JSON structures:

```
NSDictionary* dict = @{
    @"Key1": @"Value1",
    @"Key2": @"Value2",
};
```

Finally, a new literal for NSInteger (etc.) has been added:

```
NSNumber* value = @3.141;
```

Note that although this works for floating point (`@3.141F`) and doubles (`@3.141`) it does not work for `long double`s as these are not supported for wrapping by the compiler. Thus, `@3.141D` will be a compile-time error.

Owing to how the constants are defined, `@INT_MAX` is a valid valid value but `@INT_MIN` is not, since the latter is defined via a compile-time expression and not a literal in itself.

There are also extensions to boolean types:

```
NSNumber* yes = @YES;         // [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
NSNumber* no = @NO;           // [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
NSNumber* trueBool = @true;   // [NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)true]
NSNumber* falseBool = @false; // [NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)false]
```

This change has also introduced the `__objc_yes` and `__objc_no` literals to support the parsing of the types via literal value only. Their use is guarded with `#if __has_feature(objc_bool)` in the preprocessor, but developers should continue to use `YES` and `NO` in code.

Finally, both arrays and dictionaries can now be subscripted with array brackets, in use both as `lvalue` and `rvalue` expressions:

```
NSMutableArray* stuff = ...
id first = stuff[0];
stuff[0] = anotherObject;

NSMutableDictionary* moreStuff = ...
id conference = moreStuff[@"NSConf"]
moreStuff[@"SponsoredBy"] = @"NSConfDuck"
```

The array style subscripting (using an `NSUInteger`) is mapped to `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` and the corresponding `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:`, whilst the dictionary access is accessed with `objectForKeyedSubscript:` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`

The full syntax for the literals can be seen at the [Clang/LLVM website](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Note that since this answer was initially written, Clang has added support for non-literal Objective-C expressions called 'Boxed expressions'

This means that one can use `@(3+4)` as an equivalent to `@7`, and `@("Hello World")` as `@"Hello World"`. Note that a C expression which evaluates to `null` will result in an exception, and arguments such as `@(null)` are treated as a compile-time error.

It is also possible to use 'Boxed enums' for types with a known type, so

enum {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
  };

can be placed into a boxed enum type with `@(North)`, which will have the value `0`.

Boxed expressions will be available in clang 3.2 onwards. It can be tested for using the `__has_feature(objc_boxed_expressions)` preprocessor test.

Comment: There's now also autoboxed expressions, which was created after this answer was first published. I've amended the list above to include some examples of that.

Comment: I must say an `@nil` would be nice for `NSNull`.

Comment: I think "id first = stuff[@0];" is wrong. I think it must be "id first = stuff[0];" to avoid a compile-time error.

Comment: I think it's odd that NSDictionary creation uses @{}, yet for access it uses dict[key]. I don't really like the switching of bracket types. I'd rather they use dict{key} for access for consistency.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSNumber *intNumber1 = @42;
NSArray *array1 = @[@"foo", @42, @"bar", @3.14];
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = @{ @1: @"red", @2: @"green", @3: @"blue" };
```

Source: http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/02/something-wonderful-new-objective-c.html