# Are message and function prototypes no longer necessary in clang 3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, llvm, clang

I expect the following code to produce warnings about implicit declaration of functions:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation TestClass

- (void)foo {
    NSString *test = [self bar];
    NSLog(@"%@", test);
    test = baz();
    NSLog(@"%@", test);
}

- (NSString *)bar {
    return @"bar";
}

NSString *baz() {
    return @"baz";
}

@end
```

Specifically I would expect warnings about using both `bar` and `baz` before they are declared. (`bar` would be assumed to return `id` and `baz` would be assumed to return `int`.)

GCC shows both warnings, as does LLVM's Clang 2.9. Clang 3, however, can apparently figure out that `bar` and `baz` exist and what they return. **No warning appears** (unless the functions are removed).

(When `baz` is declared outside of the class, the warning still occurs. So this only applies to Objective-C!)

**Awesome!** That would allow a lot of duplication to be removed. But what is going on? Is this a language extension? Is it a compiler feature? Is it a bug? Or am I mistaken about this? I couldn't find any documentation on this, so I am wary of relying on it. **Does anybody have any insight?**

Comment: Just take it as it is - awesome! Now, if they can just fix LLDB....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS 6 documentation (now out of NDA) finally contains an official acknowledgement of this feature.

It's called "No forward method prototypes needed in @implementation block", requires Xcode 4.3
(LLVM Compiler 3.1) and is compatible with all releases of iOS.

[Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html)

That page lists all recent improvements to the compiler and Objective-C and under what constellatons they are available.

Answer (score 1):

This came up on the Apple list a few weeks ago.  It's a new feature.  There are some other things coming along like:

```
NSArray* myArray = @[ @"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];
```

as syntactic sugar for

```
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"foo", @"bar", @"baz", nil];
```

(well it's not quite a direct translation).

Also, I think there's going to be

```
array[i]
```

for

```
[array objectAtIndex: i];
```

and there will be equivalent extensions for dictionaries.

Comment: There's an SO post about the literal syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c