# In the iPhone SDK is it safe and proper to chain stringByAppendingString in line?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, concatenation

Is there a better way to achieve concatenating multiple strings in one single line? Or any advise at all when doing this.

```
NSString *string1 = @"one";
NSString *string2 = @"one";
NSString *string3 = @"one";
NSString *appendedText = @"";

[appendedText = [[string1 stringByAppendingString: string2] stringByAppendingString: string3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Safe and proper? Sure.

Let's say you have:

```
NSString *a = @"hay";
NSString *b = @"bee";
NSString *c = @"see";
```

You can use `stringByAppendingString:` to concatenate them all:

```
cat = [a stringByAppendingString:[b stringByAppendingString:c]];
```

You can use `stringByAppendingFormat:` to concatenate them all:

```
cat = [a stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", b, c];
```

You can use `stringWithFormat:`:

```
cat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", a, b, c];
```

You can put them in an array, and use `componentsJoinedByString:`:
(just for fun, using [array literal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c))

```
array = @[ a, b, c];
cat = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

You can collect them in a mutable string:

```
NSMutableString *temp = [a mutableCopy];
[temp appendString:b];
[temp appendString:b];
cat = [temp copy]; // if you want to make sure result is immutable
```

All of these methods are OK. Here's my advice for choosing one to use:

1. Use whichever one makes your code clear and easy to read.
2. When your app is working correctly, use Instruments to profile it.
3. *Only if you find out that string concatenation is causing a performance problem*, consider a different method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it answers question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringByAppendingFormat:`

`[string1  stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",string2,string3]`

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is a ref

you also have [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but in terms of syntax it will look about the same

Daniel

Comment: I had forgot all about NSMutableString thanks for reminding me. I will take this into consideration with future apps because I think it may be more clear.