# Mutable array merge array to another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two mutable arrays:

`NSMutableArray` **array1**; [containing 1,2,3,4,5]

`NSMutableArray` **array2**; [containing 9,8,7]

I want to insert **array2** values to **array1** between 3 and 4, so the result could be:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,9,8,7,4,5]
```

Again I want to remove array2 values from array1, so the result could be:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Please suggest me some best approach to achieve it.

The below links doesn't help:
[Copy object at specific index of mutable array to the end of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984269/copy-object-at-specific-index-of-mutable-array-to-the-end-of-another-array)

Comment: its fix that you want to insert array2 at 4th index into array1?

Comment: No, at any index I can insert array2, but yes at one time, it will be given the index value.

Comment: @Ren You need to add object after object 3 that fix right? Means always between object 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes it is given

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  You need to add `array2` and then remove it?  Isn't the result just going to be the same as `array1`'s initial value every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirement you can split your first array into 2 part and merge all 3 array to final array for getting expected output.

Please check this code:

```
    NSMutableArray *mutArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"9",@"8",@"7", nil];

    //You cna change index based on your requirement.
    int indexToSpit = 3;

    //Split your first array into 2 part.
    NSArray *arayFirstPart = [mutArray1 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, indexToSpit)];
    NSArray *araySecondPart = [mutArray1 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexToSpit, mutArray1.count-indexToSpit)];

    //Merge all 3 array into single array
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arayFirstPart];
    [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:mutArray2];
    [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:araySecondPart];

    NSLog(@"Combine Array : %@",finalArray);

    //For remove
    [finalArray removeObjectsInArray:mutArray2];

    NSLog(@"Split Array : %@",finalArray);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks! lemme check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 =  [1,2,3,4,5]
var array2 =  [9,8,7]
```

for inserting **array2** at **index 3** use

```
array1.insertContentsOf(array2, at: 3)
print(array1)
```

for removing you can either use

`array1 = Array(Set(array1).subtract(array2))`

which will be unordered array as we are converting a Array to Set for subtraction.

**or you can try**

```
    var array3 =  [1,2,3,4,5]
       //assuming array1 as [1,2,3,9,8,7,4,5]
    let array4 = array1.filter({array3.contains($0)}) 
    print(array4) //will give you desired ordered array
```

Comment: Thanks jagdeep, but i am using objective C.