# What does @[] mean?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-literals

I am looking at a tutorial and I am not sure what the line of code means:

```
self.objectsToShare = @[URL];
```

`URL` is an `NSURL`, and `self.objectsToShare` is an `NSArray`.

Comment: ["Apple committed a *new (as of 2012) patch* to the llvm project adding support for new Objective-C *literal syntax* for NSArray, NSDictionary and NSNumber .."](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/13/new-objectivec-literal-syntax/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a shorthand syntax for array creation.

Instead of:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:&URL count:1];
```

More information here:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 2):

It mean you are assigning to object an array
Like below:-

`NSArray*arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObject:URL];`

Samething you can write like this as well:-

`NSArray*arr=@[URL];`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with one object: `URL`.

You can create arrays and dictionaries using the @ symbol in objective c as follows:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
 @"string key":@"string value",
 (id)objectKey:(id)objectValue
};

NSArray *arr = @[(id)objectValue,@"string value"];
```