# Remove all items from array and repopulate it

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have this array:

```
NSArray *currentPath;
```

and it gets populated here:

```
currentPath = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"];
```

I need to repopulate this array again

```
NSString *newPreviousPath = [previousPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:nextItemToRemoveString withString:@""];

    currentPath = [newPreviousPath];
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Expected identifier
```

How do I fix this and accomplish this ?

Comment: what's the entire error? paste all your code?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike swift, in objective c you should do it like:

```
currentPath = @[newPreviousPath];
```

See what magic `@` symbol does in Objective C, detailed answer here: [Is there some literal dictionary or array syntax in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693698/593709)

Answer (score 0):

currentPath = [newPreviousPath];
As in here you are using Literals syntax,it is not the right way to assign a array. You need to do following
currentPath = @[newPreviousPath];