# Best way get object for key for inner key in NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Maybe this question title is not very clear. I have json as follow:

```
// {
//    "aps": {
//        "alert": {
//            "title":"nice title",
//            "body":"A nice body. $savings"
//        },
//        "content-available":"1"   //This flag set enables background processing
//    },
//    "blabla":"1",
//    "spend_amount":"$cash",
//    "save_amount":"$savings"
// }
```

To get info inside title I need to do either:

```
 NSString * _message = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] objectForKey:@"body"];
```

or define three two variables

```
id payload = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
id alert = [payload objectForKey:@"alert"];
NSString * _actionTitle = [alert objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: yes, using literals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c

Comment: `_message = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"title"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use following one line of code for getting nested Dictionary keys value:

```
[userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps.alert.title"];
```

I just Create and example and test code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *d =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [d setValue:@"A nice body. $savings" forKey:@"body"];
    [d setValue:@"nice title" forKey:@"title"];


    NSMutableDictionary *b =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [b setValue:d forKey:@"alert"];

    NSMutableDictionary *e =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [e setValue:@"1" forKey:@"content-available"];
    [e setValue:b forKey:@"aps"];

    NSLog(@"Dictioarn = %@",e);
    NSLog(@"Dictioarn = %@",[e valueForKeyPath:@"aps.alert.title"]);
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

```
Dictioarn = nice title
```

Comment: This is the best way.

Comment: `setValue:forKey:` is not cool tho...

Comment: You mean use `setObject:forKey`?

Comment: @trojanfoe so what to use instead `setValue:forKey`

Comment: i got it if we are using mutable object like `NSMutableDictionary` then we have to use `setObject:forKey` and if we are using `NSDictionary` then use `setValue:forKey`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

change objectForKey instead of valueForKey in body keyword,

```
NSString * _message = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"];
```

hope its helpful

Comment: This is the worst way.

Comment: I am new in IOS, i used above methods only, Any way thanks for your feedback